# How can I apply a global .dateDecodingStrategy for all JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder?

Tags: swift, jsondecoder, jsonencoder

I haven't found any info/similar questions here. I need to use `.iso8601` for my `JSONDecoder` and `JSONEncoder`. Current I am doing this for each HTTP call:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .tryMap(handleHTTPOutput)
    .decode(type: [TaskModel].self, decoder: decoder)
    ...
```

Is there any way to change the default value of `dateDecodingStrategy` for all the `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder`?

I was trying to do the below but it doesn't work:

```swift
JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = iso8601
```

The error says the `DateDecodingStrategy` is immutable.

Comment: You can't do this directly. However, you can create a custom subclass of the encoders and decoders with `super.init()` etc... and then use those in your app.

Comment: JSONDecoder has no subclassing notes, so you should assume it is not designed to be subclassed. Instead, you would use an extension that returns a desired configured object. As a rule, be extremely careful (and avoid if possible) subclassing types that are not explicitly designed for subclassing.

Comment: Just a side note on why this isn't possible (the answers below gives lots of other ways to approach the problem). Imagine it *were* possible to change the global settings for all JSONDecoders. This would impact any Apple and third-party frameworks that you import that use JSON internally, breaking their serializations. You really don't want this to be global. You want it to be easy to access within your system. So you should create an extension that makes it easy to configure it the way you want, but not **globally**.

Comment: @RobNapier - “has no subclassing notes, so you should assume it is not designed to be subclassed” … That’s an interesting take. I would have assumed the exact opposite, that all classes are subclass’able unless the documentation says otherwise. A “class” means, almost by definition, that it can be subclassed. And generally where you cannot subclass, or it is ill-advised, the docs are good about warning us. That having been said, subclassing is just the wrong pattern here (subclasses should extend behaviors, not change them).

Answer (score 2):

Other answers provide the syntax for using this outside of call site. No one has mentioned to use [static member lookup](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0299-extend-generic-static-member-lookup.md) for you there yet, though. That looks like this:

```swift
extension TopLevelDecoder where Self == JSONDecoder {
  static var json: Self {
    let `self` = JSONDecoder()
    self.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    return self
  }
}
```

```swift
.decode(type: [TaskModel].self, decoder: .json)
```

That's all you need if you're only ever using that decoder in `decode` functions.

---

But you probably aren't only doing that, for encoding. You can provide two static variables: one on the type, and one on the constrained protocol, to handle both use cases:

```swift
extension JSONEncoder {
  static var iso8601: JSONEncoder {
    let `self` = JSONEncoder()
    self.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    return self
  }
}

extension TopLevelEncoder where Self == JSONEncoder {
  static var json: Self { .iso8601 }
}
```

```swift
try JSONEncoder.iso8601.encode(TaskModel())
```

```swift
… // Publisher<[TaskModel], _>
.encode(encoder: .json)
```

Comment: I don't think the utility of static member lookup had really sunk in for me. Thanks. This helped.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the default value of the key/date/data strategies but you can extend both types and add static properties with the desired behavior.

For example define an `iso8601` En-/Decoder as well as a `snakeCase` En-/Decoder

```
extension JSONEncoder {
    static let iso8601 : JSONEncoder = {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
        return encoder
    }()
    
    static let snakeCase : JSONEncoder = {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
        return encoder
    }()
}

extension JSONDecoder {
    static let iso8601 : JSONDecoder = {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        return decoder
    }()
    
    static let snakeCase : JSONDecoder = {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        return decoder
    }()
}
```

The benefit is you can write

```
.decode(type: [TaskModel].self, decoder: JSONDecoder.iso8601)
```

Comment: Is it safe for an app to rely on a single instance of a `JSON[En|De]coder` for the lifetime of the app? Are they thread safe and/or reusable?

Comment: @HangarRash I suppose. `Codable` uses `JSONserialization` under the hood – which is thread-safe – and according to the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/JSONDecoder.swift) there is no shared storage.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess the only possible issue would be if different parts of the app started setting different values to other properties on the `iso8601` instance. That would make for some interesting bugs to track down.

Comment: @HangarRash - One should never assume that a reference type is thread safe (unless it is `Sendable` or the documentation otherwise makes some formal assurances to this effect). Besides, you have no assurances that some call point couldn’t mutate one or more properties of the referenced object. I would strongly advise against the `static` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, you will have to go to every spot where you are constructing a JSONEncoder/Decoder and change it. Just change them all to use a single global Encoder/Decoder.

You can store the global in an extension to avoid name pollution:

```
extension JSONEncoder {
    static let shared: JSONEncoder = {
        var res = JSONEncoder()
        res.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
        return res
    }()
}

extension JSONDecoder {
    static let shared: JSONDecoder = {
        var res = JSONDecoder()
        res.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        return res
    }()
}
```

Now do a global find/replace from `JSONDecoder().` to `JSONDecoder.shared.` and from `JSONEncoder().` to `JSONEncoder.shared.`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against subclass approach. Subclasses are best suited when extending a class with new behaviors, not when changing its behaviors.

There are a couple of approaches I would consider.

1. One is to just have a convenience initializer that takes the date decoding strategy:

   ```swift
   extension JSONDecoder { 
       /// Return new `JSONDecoder` with particular date decoding strategy
       convenience init(dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy) {
           self.init()
           self.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can do things like:

   ```swift
   URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
       .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
       .tryMap(handleHTTPOutput)
       .decode(type: [TaskModel].self, decoder: JSONDecoder(dateDecodingStrategy: .iso8601))
   ```
2. Another approach is to create your own factory method with the appropriate date decoding strategy:

   ```swift
   extension TopLevelDecoder where Self == JSONDecoder { 
       /// Return new `JSONDecoder` with `.iso8601` date decoding strategy
       static func jsonWithIso8601() -> JSONDecoder {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
           return decoder
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can do things like:

   ```swift
   URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
       .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
       .tryMap(handleHTTPOutput)
       .decode(type: [TaskModel].self, decoder: .jsonWithIso8601())
   ```
3. I generally have multiple properties I have to set up for my encoders/decoders, so I personally have a `private` (or `internal`) factory for decoders for my particular web service:

   ```swift
   private extension TopLevelDecoder where Self == JSONDecoder { 
       /// Return new `JSONDecoder` designed for the “Foobar” web service
       static func forFoobar() -> JSONDecoder {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
           decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
           …
           return decoder
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can do things like:

   ```swift
   URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
       .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
       .tryMap(handleHTTPOutput)
       .decode(type: [TaskModel].self, decoder: .forFoobar())
   ```

There are lots of variations on the theme, but hopefully this illustrates a few basic ideas.

But, as a general design principle, I would generally advise against a `static` property given that this is a reference type with its own mutable properties. You might be careful to not mutate it right now, but it is the sort of thing that bites you a year or two later when accidentally mutate one of the properties, unaware of the unintended consequences that sharing introduced.

---

Regarding your error trying to set [`DateDecodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/datedecodingstrategy/), that is not a property. It is an `enum` (for example, as used as a parameter type in the convenience initializer of my first example, above).

It would be analogous to:

```swift
enum Answer {
    case yes
    case no
}

var answer: Answer = .yes   // fine
answer = .no                // fine

Answer = .no                // ERROR: this makes no sense; `Answer` is a type, an `enum`, not a property or variable
```